# celery issuing tasks from subtasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

My "big" task works in steps: it can either terminate or spawn more tasks. In my example, I count to 5.

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
from time import sleep

@app.task
def slow_add(x):
    """Slowly counts to 5"""
    sleep(1)
    print (x)
    if x == 5:
        return x
    else:
        return slow_add.s(x+1)()
```

When I schedule the task, I get only one invocation:

```
In [48]: asks.slow_add.run(1)
1
2
3
4
5
Out[48]: 5
```

1. How to call it asynchronously? I tried different variations of apply_async, delay, but no avail.
2. I see no tasks in the celery monitor. Why?
3. How can I get intermediate state (in this case, the number between 1 and 5) while the task is asynchronously executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In My example,

```
@app.task
def test(x):
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print x
    if x == 5:
        return x
    else:
        return test.delay(x+1)
```

1. It works fine asynchronously when I used `res = test.delay(1)`
2. In Celery monitor I can see task received

   > > Received task: services.tasker.test[67f22e02-7c39-4c1d-a646-acabeb72d208]
   > > 1
   > >     
   > > Received task: services.tasker.test[9eed6d45-4931-4790-8477-3bbe75e213e4]
   > >     Task services.tasker.test[67f22e02-7c39-4c1d-a646-acabeb72d208] succeeded in 3.021544273s: None
   > > 2
   > > ...
3. You can get task state using `res.ready()`, it returns `True` when the task is finished otherwise it returns `False`

In my test case, the result are like

```
>>> res = test.delay(1)
>>> res.ready()  # before finishing task
False
>>> res.ready()  # after finishing task
True
```

or

```
def final_result(r):
    if isinstance(r.result, celery.result.AsyncResult):
         return final_result(r.result)
    else:
        return r.result
```

and use above like

```
>>> print final_result(res)
5
```

Comment: In this case I cannot get the result of the original command. I.e. it is complete after 1 second, but how do I get the 5?

Comment: No, I badly phrased the question. The task completes after 1 iteration; celery just spawns a new one without linking to the parent one. How do I get the async handler of the last task?

In other words, your example really does what I asked: creates 5 tasks. But in the end I am only interested in the result of the last one (which I can get if I have the handle).